# .val doesn't work when executed by .click

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-1.3.2

I am running jquery 1.3.2 and when I try to retrieve the value of a `<textarea>` I get a `TypeError: $(...).val is not a function`. The function outside the .click() works fine, but when I click the link, I get the error.

```
var textbox = 'textarea#Comments';
var get = $(textbox).val();
alert(get);
$(textbox).after('<a href="#" id="link">Get text</a>');
$('a#link').click(function() {
    var get = $(textbox).val(); 
    alert(get);
});
```

Edit: The problem was caused by firefox javascript console. Putting the code on the site and running it fixed the issue.

Comment: Any reason to use jquery 1.3.2?

Comment: This selector looks wrong: 'a.#link'

Comment: You should upgrade to 1.8.2

Comment: I am creating a greasemonkey script for a backend website and whenever I load a different Jquery some of the sites scripting breaks.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cb9yu/

Comment: Ah I just tested it in google chrome and it works. However the error still occurs in firefox.

Comment: Have you placed this javascript code **after** the textarea in your html document? Or are you using jquery's document ready event?

Comment: I am letting the page load, then pasting it into the firefox javascript console. Getting the value works outside the click, but inside it gives me this error upon clicking.

Comment: Thank you for your help, after everyone confirming that it works in all their browsers and with higher versions of jquery I have decided to just upgrade and fix all of this site's javascript that breaks. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('a.#link').click(function() {
    var get = $('textarea#Comments').val(); 
    //or var get = textbox.val(); 
    alert(get);
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing it. All you are doing is leaving out a variable. There is no improvement.

Comment: Your code is working on jQuery 1.6.4 and you may need to upgrade, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/VK6Rr/

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in html dom created ...

to triggering html dom created by javascript you must use `.live()`
and the code must be look like this:

```
$('a.#link').live('click',function() {
  var get = $(textbox).val(); 
  alert(get);
});
```

Only that, good luck

Comment: This is not necessary, since the click-event handler is added at the end, after the link is created and insert into the dom.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an error on your selector where you bind the click handler.

```
$('a.#link').click(function() {
```

there is an extra `.` after `a`.

Change it to

```
$('a#link').click(function() {
```

Comment: @JackCole and yet this is a fix.

Comment: Are you showing the code as it is? or did you change something? Are you sure `textbox` variable has a valid value inside the click function? Try giving it a string literal `textarea#Comments` instead of the variable value?